# Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null': A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter, text, null

I started getting an error like below in my flutter project. can you help me?

My Code :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clipboard_manager/flutter_clipboard_manager.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'URL Shortener',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
    );
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
}
class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String shortUrl = "";
  TextEditingController urlcontroller = TextEditingController();
  getData() async {
    var url = 'https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${urlcontroller.text}';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      shortUrl = result['result']['short_url'];
    });
  }

  copy(String url) {
    FlutterClipboardManager.copyToClipBoard(url).then((value) {

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text('Shorted Url Copied!'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),));
    });
  }

  buildRow(String title, String data, bool original) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: original
          ? Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                data,
              ))
          : Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(
                  title,
                ),
                Text(
                  data,
                ),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () => copy(shortUrl),
                    child: Icon(Icons.content_copy))
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/logo.svg',
          ),
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/illustration.svg',
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Let's get started!",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 60,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    "Paste your first link into the field to shorten it",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 74, 85, 10),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 130,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(59, 48, 84, 1),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/shape.svg',
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 63, 107, 1),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 40,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: urlcontroller,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 0,
                                style: BorderStyle.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: 'Shorten a link here ...'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: getData,
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          minimumSize: Size(60, 40),
                        ),
                        child: Text('SHORTEN IT!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    buildRow("Shorted Url", shortUrl, false),
                  ],
                ),
              )
        ],
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Debug Console :

A KeyUpEvent is dispatched, but the state shows that the physical key is pressed on a different logical key. If this occurs in real application, please report this bug to Flutter. If this occurs in unit tests, please ensure that simulated events follow Flutter's event model as documented in `HardwareKeyboard`. This was the event: KeyUpEvent#f92a0(physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#70053(usbHidUsage: "0x00070053", debugName: "Num Lock"), logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#00103(keyId: "0x200000103", keyLabel: "Shift Right", debugName: "Shift Right"), character: null, timeStamp: 20:32:38.369878, synthesized) and the recorded logical key LogicalKeyboardKey#00068(keyId: "0x00000068", keyLabel: "H", debugName: "Key H")
'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart':
Failed assertion: line 444 pos 16: '_pressedKeys[event.physicalKey] == event.logicalKey'

Image :
[image]

Comment: The error is thrown when the elevated button is pressed. right? did you upgrade to the flutter null safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem results most likely from this code:

```
 setState(() {
      shortUrl = result['result']['short_url'];
    });
```

You are performing this operation and assuming there will always be a `['result']['short_url']`. But this is not safe. This result only happens when the API is successful. I tried by sending a wrong formatted url and this was the result:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 2,
    "error": "This is not a valid URL, for more infos see shrtco.de/docs"
}
```

Compare it to this one, which was successful:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "code": "NaiCa",
        "short_link": "shrtco.de/NaiCa",
        "full_short_link": "https://shrtco.de/NaiCa",
        "short_link2": "9qr.de/NaiCa",
        "full_short_link2": "https://9qr.de/NaiCa",
        "short_link3": "shiny.link/NaiCa",
        "full_short_link3": "https://shiny.link/NaiCa",
        "share_link": "shrtco.de/share/NaiCa",
        "full_share_link": "https://shrtco.de/share/NaiCa",
        "original_link": "https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events"
    }
}
```

So, in your code, you need to check first if `ok` is `true` and based on that, use your setState.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
if(result['ok']){
    setState(() {
      shortUrl = result['result']['short_link'];
    });
 } else {
 print(response);
}
```

Something also very important, in the response, there is no `short_url` key, they are using `short_link`, this typo will also cause errors, and the results will always be `null`, despite the API returning a success.

Comment: I missed the short_link detail, yes you are right. Thank you very much it worked. @HuthaifaMuayyad